# Why pd.get_dummies() removing my columns from the dataset other than the one specified?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dummy-variable

I have a dastaset named as data1 which contains Titles and tags. Tags column has every row specifying a tag with comma.
I used this code:

```
data1 = data1.Tags.str.split(',').explode().reset_index()
data1 = pd.get_dummies(data1, columns=['Tags'],prefix='', prefix_sep='').groupby(['index'], as_index=False).sum().drop('index',axis=1)
```

This after printing data1.head() prints all the right dummy columns for tags but removes Titles from the dataframe i.e., data1. How do I go about to solve this problem?

EDIT:
Example of the dataset1

| Title | Tags |
| --- | --- |
| A | Java, C++ |
| B | C++, Html |
| C | Java, Python, Html |
| D | Python, C++, Html |

Expecting the result to be:

| Title | Java | C++ | Html | Python |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| B | 0 | 1 | 1 | 0 |
| C | 1 | 0 | 1 | 1 |
| D | 0 | 1 | 1 | 1 |

Comment: When you run `data1 = data1.Tags.str.split(',').explode().reset_index()` you slice as Series and remove all other columns. Please provide a clear reproducible example to better understand what you expect.

Comment: I provided an example above in the edit to better explain what I am trying to say

Answer (score 0):

Your issue didn't come from `get_dummies` but from the fact that you sliced the original DataFrame to Series in the first line.

Use [`str.get_dummies`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.get_dummies.html) directly and [`join`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html):

```
out = (df
   .drop(columns='Tags')
   .join(df['Tags'].str.get_dummies(sep=', '))
 )
```

Or, in combination with [`pop`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pop.html):

```
df = df.join(df.pop('Tags').str.get_dummies(sep=', '))
```

Output:

```
  Title  C++  Html  Java  Python
0     A    1     0     1       0
1     B    1     1     0       0
2     C    0     1     1       1
3     D    1     1     0       1
```